# VBA - How to run function when double click an inserted image

Tags: vba, excel, eventtrigger

How to trigger excel vba function when I double-click an inserted image? Right now the function is triggered by `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)`.

I could only find examples when cell is clicked or hyperlink is clicked, but couldn't find one for double-clicking on an image.

Comment: Does it need to be a double-click, not single?

Comment: Yes, double-click. I'm afraid that If Single Click,  user might accidentally click on the cell, it will triggered the function. The function will require some time to load.

Comment: is there only one image who's double-click needs to be detected?  Different actions for different pictures?

Comment: There's only one Image and only double clicked as action.

Comment: how would a click on a cell activate the code? all it would do is select the cell  .... just right click on picture ... choose "assign macro" ... click "new" .... there is your click handler sub

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the information, I didn't know beforehand. However, the event is being triggered on a single click, how can i make it to double?

Comment: click a cell in the worksheet by "accident" and tell me if the event code also triggered

Comment: use the active-x image control if you really want a double-click handler

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the help. I'm fine with single click now. Just added some  condition to the function.

Comment: Grammar and syntax improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel images don't have a Double Click event (like Access).  The worksheet has `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("Application.Caller: " & IIf(IsError(Application.Caller), Err.Description, _
        Application.Caller) & vbLf & "Target.Address: " &  _
        IIf(IsError(Target.Address), Err.Description, Target.Address))
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to check if it was an image that was double-clicked -- Application.Caller returns an error if it's not a cell that's selected.

You could put the image *behind* the cells, as a background image, and act on double click of the cells above it.

.

Or, I suppose you could make the image's assigned macro check how long it's been since the last time it was clicked.  This example will show a `MsgBox` if the image is clicked twice within 400ms:

```
Public clickedPic As String
Public lastTimer As Single

Sub Picture2_Click()
    clickedPic = Application.Caller
    If (Timer - lastTimer) < 0.5 Then
        MsgBox "doubleclick"
        er
    End If
    lastTimer = Timer
Debug.Print clickedPic, Now()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the OnAction property to the shape activating a procedure after a click event.

**Code Example with added Rectangle**

Of course you can modify this easily for an existing shape.

```
Sub AddRectangle()
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim oShape As Shape
Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
' only if you want to add a new shape, otherwise refer to Name or item no
  Set oShape = oSht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 100, 50, 50)
  oShape.Name = "MyRectangle"
' OnAction property assignes the specified procedure (e.g. "MyProcedure") to the shape object.
  oSht.Shapes("MyRectangle").OnAction = "MyProcedure"
End Sub

Sub MyProcedure()
MsgBox "Shape MyRectangle has been clicked."
End Sub
```

Comment: appreciate the hint, but see comments to OP.